# Remove empty rows based on ",,,,,,," values in the first column out of appended csv's (pandas)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to pass a dataframe that's based on serveral joined csv's to another method.

```py
col0 = ["Dov"] 
values = A, B
```

But there are some csv's that only contains ",,,,,,,," in different length in col0 at the end. 20 to 50 rows. Lenght of strange values are the same over the file but different from file to file. Rest of these columns are only filled in the regular ones.

I've played with loc, drop and dropna. Struggling for a while and searched at stackoverflow. Still no clue.

```py
def dataImport():
    header_appended = False
    concat_i = []
    progress = len(linkGenerator())
    count = 1
    print("0 of " + str(progress))
    for i in list(linkGenerator()):
        if header_appended != True:
            print("Appending : " + str(i))
            df_raw = pd.read_csv(i, header = 0, sep = ",", engine = "python", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", index_col=False )
            header_appended = True
            print("Appended.")
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("Appending : " + str(i))
            df_internal = pd.read_csv(i, sep = ",", engine = "python", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", index_col=False )
            concat_i.append(df_internal)
            print("Appended.")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(str(count) + " of " + str(progress))
            count = count + 1
            df_raw = pd.concat(concat_i, ignore_index = True)
    return df_raw
```

Works so far. Only the part after `df_raw = pd.concat(concat_i, ignore_index = True)` is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Solution was:

```py
df_raw.dropna(subset = ["Div"], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I did could do this:

[image]

Hope this helps. The str category of functions are pretty powerful within pandas. I don't what is the minimum number of "," you are seeing and also col0 needs to be str/object type.

Answer (score 0):

Thx. for trying to help me. Sadly did not work.

```py
    df_raw = df_raw[~df_raw["Div"].str.match(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,", na = False)] 
    # df_raw = df_raw.drop(df_raw["Div"] != 0, inplace = True) 
    # df_raw = df_raw.drop(["Div"] == "") 
    # df_raw = df_raw.loc[df_raw["Div"] != ""]  
    # df_raw = df_raw[(df_raw["Div"] != ",,,,,,") | (df_raw["Div"] != ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,")].copy()
```

Result every time:

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMHD1.png)

[End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojtzl.png)